# Assigning a value to a variable in a loop and printing it using korn shell

Tags: unix

I am having problem when trying to assign a value to a variable in a loop and trying to print it using korn shell. I want to use that variable in later part of my script. So I am trying to test with in the loop by printing the value of the dynamic varible I just assigned to it from my array.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
clear
BINPATH=/usr/bin
SVR_LIST=servers_list

set -A SERVERS `cat $SVR_LIST`
typeset -i i=0

while [ $i -lt ${#SERVERS[@]} ] ; do
#print ${SERVERS[$i]}
typeset -l s${i}=${SERVERS[$i]}
echo "Value of Variable is " ${s{$i}}
(( i=i+1 ))
done
```

I am getting following error.

./test.sh[12]: ${s{$i}}: bad substitution

Answer (score 0):

Try it with

```
eval echo "Value of Variable is \${s$i}"
```

You need two evaluation steps (once for `$i` and once for the rest), hence you need `eval`.